# Prevent MySQL to select the same row by compete threads

Tags: mysql

I have some table proxy. There proxies are stored. Application is multithreaded. Each thread gets proxy from proxy table. And I need to use proxies that frequency of each proxy usage must be accidentally equals. There is some field 'last_usage' with timestamp with microseconds.

Now to achieve this goal I do the next: block table, select one proxy with older last_usage, then update last_usage of selected proxy and unlock table.

table engine is inno_db.

Another my idea is to use the following solution:

```
SET @uids := null;
UPDATE footable
   SET foo = 'bar'
 WHERE fooid > 5
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) );
SELECT @uids;
```

I think it should have the same effect. Because mysql should block the row or table when update is executing. And another threads should not be able to select this row.

May I use second solution for my goal ? Which way is better or can you suggest better way ?

Comment: Note that this way of using user variables is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be to use two queries in a single transaction:

```
start transaction;

select foo_id into @foo_id
from foo_table
order by last_usage asc
limit 1
for update;

update foo_table
set last_usage = now()
where foo_id = @foo_id;

commit;
```

`FOR UPDATE` is used, to lock the selected row until the transaction is commited.

Comment: If transaction will not be commited for some reason, row will be blocked forever ?

Comment: The lock will be released on a commit or a rollback. Also when the connection is closed or timed out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an INNODB lock explained here
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html

which can be used in your case.

in your case using

```
SELECT * FROM footable WHERE fooid > 5
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) ) FOR UPDATE;
```

and then to update and get rid of the lock with same session:

```
UPDATE footable
   SET foo = 'bar'
 WHERE fooid > 5
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', fooid, @uids) );
```